# How to replace click by YES document.getElementById('snap').addEventListener('click', function()

Tags: html5-canvas, html5-video

I would like to have the below function executed automatically

```
document.getElementById('snap').addEventListener('click', function() {
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
     });
```

is ready the right choice ?

```
document.getElementById('snap').ready(function() {
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
     });
```

as suggested in other thread
or can I use boolean "yes" to replace event listener

Tested ready and failed to work

All I need is to snap photo auto run
example
    http://localhost/snapphoto.html

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try executing your function in window.onload like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // Your javascript code here
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
}
```

The function in window.onload will execute as soon as everything has been loaded, including CSS and media files.

Comment: Thank you .onload

Comment: Thank you .onload does nothing. I assume first window receives live video stream from webcam so "never loaded" ?  On the other hand, if I insert raw function only, video fails to load, so your solution is close to be final. I inserted wait(1000); function() {.... making video to stop to load

Comment: ok, I inserted sleep(1000); since sleep is correct for wait in JS But even if I insert sleep(1);  fuction fails to execute on click

Comment: follow-up  There is an excellent Photo Booth app and JS http://wolframhempel.github.io/photobooth-js/#Demo and code http://wolframhempel.github.io/photobooth-js/photobooth_min.js but single line code makes me hard to understand how it works

Comment: follow-up 4  neither sleep or wait, timeout works for JS setTimeout(function(){alert("hi")}, 1000);

Comment: follow-up 5 I am really sorry for inserting local file. The idea and example of Snap Photo comes from David https://davidwalsh.name/demo/camera.php  example and code https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera  called: Demo: Camera and Video Control with HTML5

Comment: You need to put all your code inside that function as I wrote there

Comment: All code is a single script as in demo by David. <video id="video" autoplay="autoplay" src="" height="480" width="640"></video>
<button id="snap" class="sexyButton">Snap Photo</button>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>

 <script>

  // Put event listeners into place
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {   So not sure if window loaded is when live video image is seen. Ok, I will try. thanks

Comment: Should I rewrite window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {  as top function since diving script into 2 parts (config + video load) +  image load failed again. I need to learn more about DOMContentLoaded event

Comment: Ok, I can invoke Snap Photo button via SetTimeout but if run in loop I don't get any image refresh if video image is changing.

Comment: Thank you Aenadon,   the issue is if the video frame is copied to canvas/context first time, so the next time canvas/context should be cleaned/cleared first to let new video frame to be copied and saved (I assume so). I run the same script twice to test the above, no canvas/context photo refresh. Loop works and can populate another canvas/conteext with a new video frame. But it works for another canvas/context object only.   If you know a solution or a working examples, pls let me know. Image gets refreshed if Snap Photo button clicked anyway.   thank you

Comment: Hi, it looks like my PC is old, my OPS Win32XP is old, Chrome version is old, Firefox is (?), computer is low on video memory, so longer than 5 sec setTimeout is suggested.  Life is not easy with HTML5 video webcam canvas context, video frame images in real time + Firefox or Chrome + old OS + old computer ;(